# Replacing eval() in MicrosoftAjax.js file with different code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, microsoft-ajax

The HTML/JS .aspx pages in my Asp.NET WebForm application use MicrosoftAjax.js file, But some security policies disallows the use of javascript eval() function. They claim that all instances of eval can be replaced by another (hopefully safer) function.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```

How can we replace these eval() functions with different code so that the file can surpass the security validations ?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "limited changes" - since, without `MicrosoftAjax.js` you can't load the service .js resource - which would mean writing an alternative method to make the requests etc - however, most of the eval's in that file can be rewritten - only one I'm not sure about is the one for `Array.parse` - but that looks unused anyway

Comment: `Array.parse` could theoretically be rewritten as a `JSON.parse` - so, really, you can rewrite that, remove the one for `eval('debugger')` - just means debugger won't be invoked, and the other three, in `Type.parse` and `Sys.Net._WebRequestManager.prototype` are fairly simple to rewrite too - that leaves the one in `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize` which deals with dates, that may be an issue - however, that could be replaced with a `JSON.parse` with a `reviver` to handle the odd date format in WCF

Comment: of course, I'm assuming I know which version of MicrosoftAjax.js you are using

Comment: @Bravo : Thanks, I see that there are 5 references to eval() function. I am a bit not confident in replacing these references as I am pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: which version of MicrosoftAjax.js are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MicrosoftAjax.js version 4.5.2, I can safely say the following probably won't break anything

The line numbers are a **guide only** - look for the specific code to replace

The first two are easy, single line replacements

Around line 531

```
Type.parse = function (typeName, ns) {
    var fn;
    if (ns) {
        fn = Sys.__upperCaseTypes[ns.getName().toUpperCase() + "." + typeName.toUpperCase()];
        return fn || null
    }
    if (!typeName)
        return null;
    if (!Type.__htClasses)
        Type.__htClasses = {};
    fn = Type.__htClasses[typeName];
    if (!fn) {
//replace next line
        fn = eval(typeName);
// with next line
        fn = typeName.split('.').reduce(function(r, v) { return r && r[v]; }, window);
//
        Type.__htClasses[typeName] = fn
    }
    return fn
};
```

Around line 662

```
Array.parse = function (value) {
    if (!value)
        return [];
    // replace next line
    return eval(value)
    // with next line
    return JSON.parse(value)
};
```

Next one just comment out the lines as shown

Around line 830

```
    fail: function (message) {
        this._appendConsole(message);
// comment out the next two lines
        //if (Sys.Browser.hasDebuggerStatement)
        //    eval("debugger")
    },
```

You can completely comment or remove the next function

Around line 2448

```
// comment out this whole function
//Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize = function (data, secure) {
//    if (data.length === 0)
//        throw Error.argument("data", Sys.Res.cannotDeserializeEmptyString);
//    try {
//        var exp = data.replace(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer._dateRegEx, "$1new Date($2)");
//        if (secure && Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer._jsonRegEx.test(exp.replace(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer._jsonStringRegEx, "")))
//            throw null;
//        return eval("(" + exp + ")")
//    } catch (a) {
//        throw Error.argument("data", Sys.Res.cannotDeserializeInvalidJson)
//    }
//};
```

the `get_object` method needs to be replaced

Around line 3938

```
// replace this function
    get_object: function () {
        if (!this._resultObject)
            this._resultObject = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(this.get_responseData());
        return this._resultObject
    },
// with this function
    get_object: function () {
        if (!this._resultObject) {
            this._resultObject = JSON.parse(this.get_responseData(), function wcfReviver(key, value) {
                if (typeof value !== "string") {
                    return value;
                }
                var d = value.match(/^\/Date\((-?\d+)(?:[+-]\d{4}|)\)\/$/);
                return d && d.length === 2 ? new Date(+d[1]) : value;
            });
        }
        return this._resultObject
    },
```

And another, simple, single line replacement

Around line 4166

```
    executeRequest: function (webRequest) {
        var executor = webRequest.get_executor();
        if (!executor) {
            var failed = false;
            try {
// replace next line
                var executorType = eval(this._defaultExecutorType);
// with next line
                var executorType = this._defaultExecutorType.split('.').reduce(function(r, v) { return r && r[v]; }, window);
// 
                executor = new executorType
            } catch (a) {
                failed = true
            }
            webRequest.set_executor(executor)
        }
        if (executor.get_aborted())
            return;
        var evArgs = new Sys.Net.NetworkRequestEventArgs(webRequest),
        handler = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("invokingRequest");
        if (handler)
            handler(this, evArgs);
        if (!evArgs.get_cancel())
            executor.executeRequest()
    }
```

I can confirm that I applied these changes to a a development testing site, and it kept working. I even applied it to the production version of the site for one sparsely used section that, for some reason specifically loads MicrosoftAjax.js (in the rest of our site using, this file is loaded as part of a common header), and nothing broke there either - I then even tried changing the global common section, and the production site didn't skip a beat.

That said, no warranties implied or given, if you break something you get to keep all pieces.

Comment: Thank you so much, Let me try out these changes and see if it is working !

Comment: @DotNetSpartan - if your file is the same as `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.js` then you should be good

Comment: I can confirm this works for MicrosoftAjax.js version 4.6 too.